# Can I control applet font from HTML-code?

Tags: java, parameters, font-size, japplet

I like to adjust the font-size from outside the applet (JApplet := Swing-Applet), from the surrounding/calling HTML code, like

```
<PARAM name="java_arguments" value="-D...">
```

I remember vaguely, that there is the possibility to call a classical Java-Application with

```
java -Dsome.font.property=xy proj.App
```

and I guess there is a mapping from the -D-switch to (J)Applet-params, but I don't find an overview. When I remember correctly, there are 10 or 20 different font settings option, menufont, tooltipfont, normal font, dialog font, and not easy to guess which one influences what.

Since it needs more time to recompile the class, build a new archive and to reload the page than editing the HTML, and reloading that, I would prefer to set the font (monospaced) and  font-size in HTML.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the font programatically, calling a method from javascript to java:

```
 function modifyFont(valueOfFontSize)
 {
      document.theJavaApplet.aPublicMethodInsideTheApplet(valueOfFontSize);
 }
```

And,,,, if you have an "applet" element, put the "SCRIPTABLE" attribute inside:

```
 <applet name="theJavaApplet" scriptable="true" [...etc...] ></applet>
```

but, if you use the "object" element....

```
  <object [....]> 
     <param name...>
     <param name...>
     <param name...>
     <param name="scriptable" value="true">
  </object>
```

If this doesn't works:

```
       <applet name="theJavaApplet" mayscript="true" [...etc...] ></applet>
```

of if it's an object:

```
       <param name="mayscript" value="yes">
```

Comment: Ok, I will try that (both). I don't need to manipulate the font dynamically, so I guess modifyFont doesn't need to take a parameter - I just embed it with `<!--script ...> ...</script>` into the page where the applet is? I have nearly no experience wiht js. `mayscript=""` is empty, or should't it be "true"? For the second approach, I need both: mayscript and scriptable? Is `version` mandatory, and is it the exact or at least version?

Comment: Ok, I looked. It took some time, since firefox doesn't use my appletplugin anymore. I found a way to make it work in Opera, but my signature was expired. How do I do a signature - last time I did it was 10 years before! :) Ok, it is working, JApplet rewritten (added aPubMethInJapplet), html-code rewritten, js inserted, but how is the JS-code called - it will not trigger itself. I need some onLoad or something? I don't need some fancy stuff here with dynamic parameter passing. Just one single resizement is all I need.

Comment: Hohoho. With:


`<script type="text/javascript">window.onload = function(){document.theJavaApplet.aPubMethInJapplet()}</script>`


the script will trigger itself :P.

Comment: I tried it offline and [online](http://home.arcor.de/hirnstrom/minis/telno2alpha/telnojapplet.html), with Firefox, Opera and appletvierwer, with mayscript and scriptable - it doesn't work. I added a System.out message in the triggered method to verify it gets called, but I guess appletviewer doesn't perform Javascript, and the browsers don't pipe it through, even if started from the commandline. I'm sorry for your work not being honored, but since it doesn't work for me - what shall I do? I try to fill the TextField with a value, which is better testable than font size, but to no success.

Comment: I made a js-alert to verify, that the js is called, and it is. I don't get an error either. I use a code shrinking program, proguard, but tried and failed without, too. The [source code is here, btw.](http://home.arcor.de/hirnstrom/minis)